# Is it unfair to quit PhD and leave with a masters?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science

I am a college junior looking for CS PhD programs. I actually want to go for a masters degree but it is super hard to get funding. I have had research experience, but I did not enjoy it too much. I have been thinking of applying to PhD programs and then leaving with a masters. Should I take this path? If I do get admitted, obviously, my initial goal would be to go ahead and complete the PhD but this is not too likely since I did not enjoy my summer research too much and I would rather work in industry. To reiterate, I will be applying to PhD programs with a BA degree.

Comment: If you would rather work in industry, go get a job in industry.  You likely do not need a masters.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes, it's unethical to mislead the school about your intentions.

But the other information in your question is mitigating. If your "initial goal would be to go ahead and complete the PhD" then you are not applying under false pretenses. Perhaps you did not enjoy your research experience because you were not well prepared for it, or it was a project that did not suit you. As a PhD student you should have more freedom to find something suitable.

You are only a junior, so have a year to think about this. You could also consider an industry job and a return to graduate school with industrial experience behind you.